# how to remove space from filename in php as well as jquery

Tags: php, jquery

> File name can change but the extension not.

I want to remove unnecessary space from the filename and keep file name extension safe.

> Input file name:  image  shhs dsjdsk    .jpg
>
> Output file name: imagsshhsdsjdsk.jpg

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Ok it's solved , i have asked i know it is easy to solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery [Check Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rkb57/1022/)

```
var str = 'image shhs dsjdsk .jpg';
document.write( str.replace(/\s/g, '') );
```

php [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
 $getfilename =  str_replace(' ', '_', $fileName);
```

Comment: There is no jquery in you js example!

Comment: ill add it now @Justinas

Comment: Still no jQuery, pure JS

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace(' ', '_', $fileName)`. In JS it's `fileName.replace(' ', '_');`
`----------------------^---- Or just '' to remove space`

If you have multiple spaces in same position `file  name    heere.jpg` than you need to use regex `/\s+/` for that.

```
preg_replace('/\\s+/', '_', $fileName);
fileName.replace(/\s+/, '_');
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces, use str_replace:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

Whitespace, use preg_replace:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

In jQuery

```
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

```
$new_file_name=str_replace(" ","",$file_name);
rename ($file_name, $new_file_name);
```